# getting 'illegal interface qualifier' error in core data entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Please find following screenshots. I am getting 'illegal interface qualifier' error while importing `FormField.h` file.

[image]

I don't understand why I am getting this error. It is really embracing.

Comment: It looks OK, which means the error is probably somewhere else.  Probably in the header file included before it, for example.  Are you saying that file is `FormField.h`?  If so it doesn't define the type `FormField`.

Comment: @trojanfoe It is defined in FieldMapping.m file.